# How to model a building with square ground and circular roof

Tags: modeling

I am trying to create this kind of building with a square ground and a circle on top.

How would you start to create this figure? What would be the first approach?

[image: figure I am trying to make in blender...]

Answer (score 1):

You can start with a sphere.  Create then a cube of the same dimensions.
Use the cube as intersect object in a boolean modifier to create the base shape.

[image]

Apply the modifier.

Enter edit mode and delete the bottom half of the object.

[image]

Extrude and finesse at will.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another way could be using 5 booleans, cutting (difference) from a base half sphere from 5 different cubic meshes:

[image]

In this way you can adjust each of cutting shapes to taste...

You can even subtract cylindric shapes to cut from the arches, always with booleans:

[image]

..you get the idea...

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is start with those arches there. That seems to be the most complicated area of the mesh. Then, connect the faces on the bottom to make a square. Add a circle to the top and fill the holes with faces. For any mesh in general, start out with the simple shapes that will be hardest to add later and build out from there

Comment: hey, thx for the tip. Sound good. Never thought of it like that. I'll give it a go. Thx!